# Activate a window in an application with a title

Tags: applescript

Trying to figure out how to activate a window in iTerm with a particular name/title with applescript. My latest effort:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "iTerm2"
  set winlist to every window
  repeat with win in winlist
    set the_title to title of window win
    if the_title contains "Development" then
      activate win
    end if
  end repeat
end tell
```

But I'm getting this error:

`execution error: iTerm got an error: Can’t make title of window (window id 203) into type specifier. (-1700)`

The window is in full screen mode so I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: An **iTerm** _window_ does not have a `title` _property_, however, it does have a `name` _property_. So changing `title` to  `name` will eliminate the current error. But, that alone will not fix everything. Just making that change will cause a different error and to get past that, remove `window` from in front of `win` so you'll have `set the_title_ to name of win`. That still doesn't get you where you want to go because `activate` is relative to the _application_ not a particular _window_.  From the the **AS** language guide "Brings an application to the front, launching it if necessary."

Comment: Yeah, I tried `name` as well. No dice. I went a completely different route. But now my issue is getting a window in full screen mode ot be front most. Not sure it can be done.

Comment: I take that back. You were right. Need to use the name and get rid the window bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me under **macOS High Sierra**, in **Script Editor**, to switch to the *full screen window* containing the target *name*:

```applescript
tell application "iTerm"
    set winlist to every window
    repeat with win in winlist
        set the_title to name of win
        if the_title contains "Development" then
            activate
            set index of win to 1
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

If the target *window* is not in *full screen* is just raises it to the front.

Comment: Yes, this is very similar to something I came up with. I'm working through one minor annoyance where if run the script from another iterm window on a different monitor, that iterm window stays active. I can live with this, though.

Comment: @StevieD, I was testing from a system that has a single monitor.